# how to fix DownloadFile error in powershell in windows10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I ran cmd as administrator and input:

- start powershell

when open the powershell, I input:

- $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
- $client.DownloadFile("https://www.cse.ust.hk/msbd5003/data/fruits.txt","D:\IT\fruits.txt")

here is the error information:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
At line:1 char:1
 + $client.DownloadFile("https://www.cse.ust.hk/msbd5003/data/fruits.txt ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException    
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I tried adding `$ client.Credentials = Get-Credential` while it did not work.

Comment: useful text >> images. If an image is referenced, the relevant details should still be extracted.

Comment: Code in images is not useful. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the reasons not to use images. Also, *something goes wrong* is not a useful problem description. You may find that your experiences at this site will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask], before you begin posting here.

Comment: Thank you for the advices of asking questions in a better way. I have already modified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that since you're connecting through https you may need to set a more secure schannel protocol to communicate with the site you're trying to download from.

add this line indicating security protocol before your webclient request

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://www.cse.ust.hk/msbd5003/data/fruits.txt","D:\IT\fruits.txt")
```

Alternately, if you are only running this script from one machine, you can set .NET to use secure protocols by default.

You can read more about it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

```
Key - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\[Wow6432Node\]Microsoft\.NETFramework\<VERSION>
Name - SchUseStrongCrypto
Value - 1
```

Also, the native PowerShell cmdlet `invoke-webrequest` may simplify your request.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.cse.ust.hk/msbd5003/data/fruits.txt" -OutFile "D:\IT\fruits.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! I have tried all the ways you said above and they all fix my problem! Thanks again.

Comment: If you somehow get to these comments, but didn't try the Invoke-WebRequest version suggested... try it. I had a situation where the .DownloadFile() approach was failing, but replacing it with Invoke-WebRequest made it work.